# Issue In joomla custom dropdown list development

Tags: joomla2.5

For the past 3 days, I've been stuck on a dropdown list development using joomla 2.5, I have to retrieve data from database and show this data in a drop down the steps I followed are mentioned below:

Inside the models folder I have created a new model inside fields folder and name this file "fieldname.php"

Now the file "Models/fields/fieldname.php" contains following source code:

```
    <?php

    defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

    jimport('joomla.html.html');
    jimport('joomla.form.formfield');
    jimport('joomla.form.helper');
    JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

    class JFormFieldMyCompany extends JFormFieldList
    {

            protected $type = 'MyCompany';

             public function getOptions()
            {
                    // Initialize variables.
                    $options = array();

                    $db     = JFactory::getDbo();
                    $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

                    $query->select('id As value,name As text');
                    $query->from('#_k2_tags AS a');
                    $query->order('a.name');
                    $db = $this->getDbo();

                    // Get the options.
                    $db->setQuery($query);

                    $options = $db->loadObjectList();

                    // Check for a database error.
                    if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
                            JError::raiseWarning(500, $db->getErrorMsg());
                    }
                    print_r($options);exit;
                    return $options;
            }
    }
```

after that inside my model filter.php I added the following code.

**Models/filter.php**:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.modeladmin');

class FiltersModelFilter extends JModelAdmin
{

    //Add this handy array with database fields to search in
        protected $searchInFields = array('text','a.name');

//Override construct to allow filtering and ordering on our fields
        public function __construct($config = array()) {
                $config['filter_fields']=array_merge($this->searchInFields,array('a.name'));
                parent::__construct($config);
        }

    public function getTable($type = 'Filter', $prefix = 'FiltersTable', $config = array())
    {
        return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
    }




    protected function loadFormData()
    {
        $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_filters.edit.filter.data', array());

        if (empty($data)) {
            $data = $this->getItem();
        }

        return $data;
    }
    public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
    {
        $form = $this->loadForm('com_filters.filter', 'filter', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));

        return $form;
    }
     protected function getListQuery(){
                $db = JFactory::getDBO();
                $query = $db->getQuery(true);

                //CHANGE THIS QUERY AS YOU NEED...
                $query->select('id As value, name As text')
                        ->from('#_k2_tags AS a');




                // Filter search // Extra: Search more than one fields and for multiple words
                $regex = str_replace(' ', '|', $this->getState('filter.search'));
                if (!empty($regex)) {
                        $regex=' REGEXP '.$db->quote($regex);
                        $query->where('('.implode($regex.' OR ',$this->searchInFields).$regex.')');
                }

                // Filter company
                $company= $db->escape($this->getState('filter.name'));
                if (!empty($company)) {
                        $query->where('(a.name='.$company.')');
                }

                // Filter by state (published, trashed, etc.)
                $state = $db->escape($this->getState('filter.state'));
                if (is_numeric($state)) {
                        $query->where('a.published = ' . (int) $state);
                }
                elseif ($state === '') {
                        $query->where('(a.published = 0 OR a.published = 1)');
                }

                //echo $db->replacePrefix( (string) $query );//debug
                return $query;
        }

        /**
         * Method to auto-populate the model state.
         *
         * Note. Calling getState in this method will result in recursion.
         *
         * @since       1.6
         */
        protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null)
        {
                // Initialise variables.
                $app = JFactory::getApplication('administrator');

                // Load the filter state.
                $search = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.search', 'filter_search');
                //Omit double (white-)spaces and set state
                $this->setState('filter.search', preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $search));

                //Filter (dropdown) state
                $state = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.published', 'filter_state', '', 'string');
                $this->setState('filter.state', $state);

                //Filter (dropdown) company
                $state = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.name', 'filter_company', '', 'string');
                $this->setState('filter.name', $state);

                //Takes care of states: list. limit / start / ordering / direction
                parent::populateState('a.name', 'asc');
        }

}
```

Inside the "Views/filter/view.html.php"

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view');

class FiltersViewFilter extends JView
{
    protected $item;
    protected $form;
    protected $state;
    protected $sortColumn;
    protected $sortDirection;
    protected $searchterms;

    public function display($tpl = null)
    {

        $this->item = $this->get('Item');
        $this->state = $this->get('State');
        $this->form = $this->get('Form');
         $this->state= $this->get('State');

                //Following variables used more than once
                $this->sortColumn = $this->state->get('list.ordering');
                $this->sortDirection= $this->state->get('list.direction');
                $this->searchterms= $this->state->get('filter.search');
        $this->addToolbar();

      parent::display($tpl);
    }

    public function addToolbar()
    {
        if ($this->item->ID) {
            JToolBarHelper::title(JText::_('Filter Title'));
        } else {
            JToolBarHelper::title(JText::_('Add Filter Title'));
        }

        JToolBarHelper::apply('filter.apply', 'JTOOLBAR_APPLY');
        JToolBarHelper::save('filter.save', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE');
        JToolBarHelper::save2new('filter.save2new', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE_AND_NEW');

        JToolBarHelper::cancel('filter.cancel');
    }
}
```

inside the **views/filter/tmpl/default.php**

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die; 
//Get companie options
JFormHelper::addFieldPath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/models/fields');
$companies = JFormHelper::loadFieldType('MyCompany', false);
$companyOptions=$companies->getOptions(); // works only if you set your field getOptions on public!!
//Get companie options
?>
<form action="index.php?option=com_filters&amp;ID=<?php echo $this->item->ID ?>"
    method="post" name="adminForm" class="form-validate">

   <fieldset id="filter-bar">
                <div class="filter-search fltlft">
                        <input type="text" name="filter_search" id="filter_search" value="<?php echo $this->escape($this->searchterms); ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('Search in Names, etc.'); ?>" />
                        <button type="submit">
                                <?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER_SUBMIT'); ?>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" onclick="document.id('filter_search').value='';this.form.submit();">
                                <?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER_CLEAR'); ?>
                        </button>
                </div>
                <div class="filter-select fltrt">
                        <select name="filter_state" class="inputbox" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                <option value="">
                                        <?php echo JText::_('JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED');?>
                                </option>
                                <?php echo JHtml::_('select.options', JHtml::_('jgrid.publishedOptions', array('archived'=>false)), 'value', 'text', $this->state->get('filter.published'), true);?>
                        </select>

                        <select name="filter_type" class="inputbox" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                <option value=""> - Select Company - </option>
                                <?php echo JHtml::_('select.options', $companyOptions, 'value', 'text', $this->state->get('filter.name'));?>
                        </select>

                </div>
        </fieldset>
<div class="width-60 fltlft">
        <fieldset class="adminform">
            <ul class="adminformlist">
                <?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset() as $field): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $field->label; ?>
                    <?php echo $field->input; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>

        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
</form>
```

Please help me in identification of my error I need to sort out issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Is the file actually called `fieldname.php` or `mycompany.php`, because it should be the latter based on the name of the class in your code? Also, what is in the xml file for the form that outlines the different input fields of the form?

Answer (score 0):

change this Models/fields/fieldname.php to Models/fields/mycompany.php

also change from JFormFieldMyCompany to JFormFieldMycompany

and protected $type = 'MyCompany'; to protected $type = 'mycompany';